# Detect Folders or Files on Gridview on UWP

Tags: c#, image, gridview, uwp, directory

I have files and folders in the "koleksibuku" folder. I want to show folders and files into the gridview. How do I detect whether in the "koleksibuku" folder there are folders or files?

Note:

- When a folder using the image:"ms-appx:///images/folders_png8761.png"
- When a file using data binding
- Folder created by the user with the folder name in accordance with the wishes of the user

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of subfolders by calling `GetFoldersAsync()` on a [`StorageFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227230).

Here's how to use it to get a list of folders from the music folder (requires "Music Library" capability).

```
var downloadsFolder = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;

foreach (var folder in await downloadsFolder.GetFoldersAsync())
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Folder: {folder.DisplayName}");
}
```

Assuming you've created your "koleksibuku" folder in your apps local folder you would get it with something like this.

```
var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

var myFolder = await localFolder.GetFolderAsync("koleksibuku");

myFolder.GetFoldersAsync();
```